# Identifying cells that are empty or showing #REF! error in a given range

Tags: excel, vba

My code is not working properly.  It's only showing the first empty cell T10 but cells from T10 to T15 are all empty.  I would also like to identify cells that are showing #REF! in them.  I don't need the address of empty cells (as there could be quite a few on bigger scale) but would like to know the address of cells with #REF!  Thank you!

```
Sub Identiycells()
Dim Cancel As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("a", "b"))
For Each cell In sh.Range("T6:T18")
     If IsEmpty(cell) 'Or showing #REF! Then
         MsgBox "Data Missing or Formula error" & cell.Address
    Application.Goto cell, True
    Cancel = True
    Exit For
    End If
Next cell
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: The fact that you may have `#REF!` errors in those cells suggests to me that they all have formulas and while some formulas are returning zero-length strings (e.g. `""`) there are actually no truly blank cells that can be identified with the [IsEmpty function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the errors in a String and only report once at the end. For checking `#REF` or other errors you can test with `IsError(cell.value)`.

As you are going through different sheets, it might be good to specify which sheet the cells are on. You can get a cell reference including its sheet with `Split(cell.address(External:=True), "]")(1)`.

Suggested code:

```
Sub Identiycells()
    Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim report as String ' collect all errors
    Dim errorMsg as String ' error for current cell
    Dim errorCell as Range ' cell to focus at the end

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("a", "b"))
        For Each cell In sh.Range("T6:T18")
            errorMsg = ""
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                 errorMsg = "Data Missing"
                 If errorCell Is Nothing Then Set errorCell = cell
            ElseIf IsError(cell.value) Then
                 errorMsg = "Invalid Reference"
                 Set errorCell = cell
            End If
            If errorMsg <> "" Then 
                report = report & errorMsg & " in " & _
                    Split(cell.address(External:=True), "]")(1) & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next cell
    Next sh
    If Not errorCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox report
        Application.Goto errorCell, True
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you the prompt reply.  On execution it comes up with run-time error 13 - type mismatch.  It highlight the following line in yellow:                   ElseIf cell = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then

Comment: btw - excellent point re looping different sheets and i need to know which sheets have the erros.  without this i wouldn't know where to look as i have over 20 sheets.

Comment: Ah, yes, it should read `cell.value = CVErr(xlErrRef)` . Fixed that. There might be other errors, as I am not on an OS with VBA capabilities right now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Strange, following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839168.aspx) it should work. Another way to do it, although it captures other errors as well, is `ElseIf IsError(cell.value) Then`. Could you try that?

Comment: it works fine now with Elself Is Error.... It brings up all the cells that have erros and i have validated them and so it's 100% accurate in its execution, nice work! Thank you!!    Is there a way to identify the sheet the errors are appearing on?

Comment: I would have expected that the error messages would have mentioned the scheet, like "Data Missing in 'Sheet10'!T12". That was the purpose of `Split(cell.address(External:=True), "]")(1)`.

Comment: you are 100% correct, again!. I've just looked closely and it does show the sheet name.  An oversight on my part, sorry!  I cannot thank you enough!